# VSCode Find / Replace History

Tags: visual-studio-code

New to VSCode and notice there's not a dropdown history of previous find/replace strings. I am also striking out on finding this functionality via extensions.

Most every editor I've ever used has had this, so I find its absence conspicuous.

I see exact and similar feature requests on github, but alas it could never get the required 20+ votes in time before it was closed. I was prepared to open another feature request, but the directions when opening a new feature request state

`<!-- Please search existing issues to avoid creating duplicates. -->`

so I'm uncertain of the protocol. Does this only mean active tickets?

The [closed feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92222) garnered 9 votes, so there was some interest.

Comment: Try the up/down arrows.  There was placeholder text in those input fields to that effect but it is easy to miss (and the fields have to be blank to see it again).

Answer (score 4):

Use the up and down arrows.  There is placeholder text to mention this - see the gif - but it is easy to miss.  Not as nice as a dropdown though as you have to cycle through recent entiries.

[image: find and replace history]

Comment: I should have been clearer that I was aware of the existing history. Sorry about that.
Being able to go directly to the entry you want via dropdown is what I was after. Should I just create a new feature request even though a closed one already exists?

Comment: how to activate this search history?
is there a video ?

Comment: @Erhy You just arrow up or down to go forward and backward through recent entries when you have focus in the Find or Replace field.

Answer (score 3):

The up/down cursor prompt only works per session and hence, only if you have already done a search.  I too use a regular expression routinely from session to session, so I have to open up a notepad file that has my patterns then copy them to the search/replace window.  Royal pain.

And I agree, there should be a drop-down.